# Tipsy bug tooltip freezes onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, tipsy

My tipsy tooltip freezes onclick.

My Jquery:

```
    <script> 
                $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('.example-1').tipsy({gravity: 's'});
                });

  </script>
```

My HTML:

```
<span class="example-1" original-title="Med DK domæne &amp; opretted DK domæne &amp; opretted DK domæne &amp; opretted DK domæne &amp; opretted DK domæne &amp; opretted DK domæne &amp; oprettelse"><img src="/images/ja.png?1312739112" class="example-1" alt="Ja" original-title=""></span>
```

Please comment if you know a similar jquery tooltip plugin

Comment: Just curious: What's original-title for an attribute?

Comment: It is the text that appear in the tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided seems to function fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ScAYd/1/

Is there something you've left out of your example that could be causing issues? Are you receiving any javascript errors?